# How to perform auto-login in Magento2 admin?

Tags: magento2, admin, login

For M1 i had a php file which took care of logging into admin, now i need the same for M2 but i can't get it to work.

This is my external file:

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

class TestApp
    extends \Magento\Framework\App\Http
    implements \Magento\Framework\AppInterface {

    public function launch()
    {
        $areaCode = 'adminhtml';
        $username = 'admin';
        $this->_state->setAreaCode($areaCode);
        $this->_objectManager->configure($this->_configLoader->load($areaCode));

        /** @var \Magento\User\Model\User $user */
        $user = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\User\Model\User')->loadByUsername($username);

        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $session */
        $session = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session');
        $session->setUser($user);
        $session->processLogin();

        if ($session->isLoggedIn()) {
            /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\UrlInterface $backendUrl */
            $backendUrl = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Backend\Model\UrlInterface');
            $path = $backendUrl->getStartupPageUrl();
            $url = $backendUrl->getUrl($path);
            $url = str_replace('autologin.php', 'index.php', $url);
            echo $url;
            //header('Location:  '.$url);
        } else {
            echo "login failed";
        }
        exit;
    }
}

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('TestApp');
$bootstrap->run($app);
```

The session returns isLoggedIn = true and i receive the URL:
http://local.domain.dev/index.php/admin/admin/dashboard/index/key/2e3a171171d22a5c2331780f874911ba95824f6a6d0e73894771bf9a40f26ce9/

If i visit that link or if i enable the header() part, i receive the login form :(

I see that i'm missing a cookie (which is set when login form is shown) and i traced it to `Magento\Backend\Model\Session\AdminConfig` but i'm a bit lost putting them together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the missing link - posting here if anyone will ever need it :D

```
public function launch()
{
    $areaCode = 'adminhtml';
    $username = 'admin';

    $this->_request->setPathInfo('/admin');
    $this->_state->setAreaCode($areaCode);
    $this->_objectManager->configure($this->_configLoader->load($areaCode));

    /** @var \Magento\User\Model\User $user */
    $user = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\User\Model\User')->loadByUsername($username);

    /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $session */
    $session = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session');
    $session->setUser($user);
    $session->processLogin();

    if ($session->isLoggedIn()) {
        $cookieManager = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface');
        $cookieValue = $session->getSessionId();
        if ($cookieValue) {
            $sessionConfig = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Backend\Model\Session\AdminConfig');
            $cookiePath = str_replace('autologin.php', 'index.php', $sessionConfig->getCookiePath());
            $cookieMetadata = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory')
                ->createPublicCookieMetadata()
                ->setDuration(3600)
                ->setPath($cookiePath)
                ->setDomain($sessionConfig->getCookieDomain())
                ->setSecure($sessionConfig->getCookieSecure())
                ->setHttpOnly($sessionConfig->getCookieHttpOnly());
            $cookieManager->setPublicCookie($session->getName(), $cookieValue, $cookieMetadata);
        }

        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\UrlInterface $backendUrl */
        $backendUrl = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Backend\Model\UrlInterface');
        $path = $backendUrl->getStartupPageUrl();
        $url = $backendUrl->getUrl($path);
        $url = str_replace('autologin.php', 'index.php', $url);
        header('Location:  '.$url);
        exit;
    }
    return $this->_response;
}
```

This is the whole function from my question class and it works!

Comment: For M2.1 there is extra few lines that need to be added after last line of $cookieManager:

 `
           if (class_exists('Magento\Security\Model\AdminSessionsManager')) {
                /** @var \Magento\Security\Model\AdminSessionsManager $adminSessionManager */
                $adminSessionManager = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Security\Model\AdminSessionsManager');
                $adminSessionManager->processLogin();
            }
`

(I can't get the code to display properly... :/)

Comment: To make it work on 2.1.2 I had to replace $session->getName() with $sessionConfig->getName(). Before that it created session cookie with name 'PHPSESSID' and correct name is 'admin'

Comment: setAreaCode is not working, it seems like need to use emulateAreaCode, but not sure the value for 2nd and 3rd argument.

Answer (score 1):

Here is free extension with autologin for M2 implementation https://github.com/rogyar/magento2-autologin , work good on 2.2

Answer (score 0):

> **Try This Code**

```
<?php
/*
 * @author      Mahesh Makwana
 */
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Area;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $objectManager;

    protected $request;

    protected $configLoader;

    protected $adminUser;

    protected $authSession;

    protected $cookieManager;

    protected $adminConfig;

    protected $cookieMetadataFactory;

    protected $adminSessionsManager;

    protected $urlInterface;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ConfigLoaderInterface $configLoader,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
        \Magento\User\Model\UserFactory $adminUser,
        \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $authSession,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface $cookieManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory $cookieMetadataFactory,
        \Magento\Backend\Model\Session\AdminConfig $adminConfig,
        \Magento\Security\Model\AdminSessionsManager $adminSessionsManager,
        \Magento\Backend\Model\UrlInterface $urlInterface,
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager

    ) {
        $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->adminUser = $adminUser;
        $this->authSession = $authSession;
        $this->cookieManager = $cookieManager;
        $this->cookieMetadataFactory = $cookieMetadataFactory;
        $this->adminConfig = $adminConfig;
        $this->adminSessionsManager = $adminSessionsManager;
        $this->urlInterface = $urlInterface;
        $this->configLoader = $configLoader;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Execute.
     *
     * @return Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
        try {
            $username = 'admin'; // add your admin user name

            $this->request->setPathInfo('/admin');

            $this->objectManager->configure($this->configLoader->load(Area::AREA_ADMINHTML));

            /** @var \Magento\User\Model\User $user */
            $user = $this->adminUser->create()->loadByUsername($username);

            /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $session */
            $this->authSession->setUser($user);
            $this->authSession->processLogin();
            if ($this->authSession->isLoggedIn()) {
                $cookieValue = $this->authSession->getSessionId();
                if ($cookieValue) {
                    $cookiePath = $this->adminConfig->getCookiePath();
                    $cookieMetadata = $this->cookieMetadataFactory
                        ->createPublicCookieMetadata()
                        ->setDuration(3600)
                        ->setPath($cookiePath)
                        ->setDomain($this->adminConfig->getCookieDomain())
                        ->setSecure($this->adminConfig->getCookieSecure())
                        ->setHttpOnly($this->adminConfig->getCookieHttpOnly());
                    $this->cookieManager->setPublicCookie($this->adminConfig->getName(), $cookieValue, $cookieMetadata);

                    /** @var \Magento\Security\Model\AdminSessionsManager $adminSessionsManager */
                    $this->adminSessionsManager->processLogin();

                    $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->urlInterface->getUrl('admin/dashboard/index'));
                    return $resultRedirect;
                } else{
                    $this->messageManager->addError(__('invalid cookie value.'));
                }
            } else {
                $this->messageManager->addError(__('invalid admin user.'));
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addError(__('Something went wrong while login to admin.'));
        }

        $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
        return $resultRedirect;
    }
}
```