# Login into Magento 2 site from external site

Tags: magento2, api, login, rest-api, external

I have a site outside Magento's domain and I should allow Magento customer to login into Magento Store from this external site. Being completely new to Magento , I don't know how to implement this service. I was able to allow registration to Magento from an external site using REST API, but I can't find a similar way to login using REST services.

Answer (score 0):

You can use REST API also. Magento 2 framework builds in already [a list of useful API functions](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/rest/list.html).

### Token-based authentication

> To make a web API call from a client such as a mobile application, you
> must supply an authentication token on the call. The token acts like
> an electronic key that lets you access the API.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-token.html

So, in your case, for example, we have a login form on your site. We have two input fields: username and password. In your controller, we can get these values and pass to the Magento API. A successful response will return with a token which is used for authentication on the Magento side.

```
$username = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password']

$userData = array("username" => $username, "password" => $password);
$ch = curl_init("http://mage21.loc/rest/V1/integration/customer/token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($userData));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Content-Lenght: " . strlen(json_encode($userData))));

$token = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: ok, but then how can I set session cookie for customer so  that he results logged into magento?

Comment: Where you want to set the cookie?

Comment: in the same php script that I wrote, I'd like to set session cookie into customer browser and then redirect him to magento site , being already logged in :)

Comment: Seem that you want to log in to Magento site automatically?

Comment: yes that's right

Comment: On the Magento side, you should create a custom controller. On another site, you build the logic for redirection with POST values: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/122797/how-to-perform-auto-login-in-magento2-admin

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh did you succeed ? Do you have some code to share ? i tried many hours with magento 2.2.6 :/

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution :
- On external site (on sub-domain) i created a cookie with magento token (generated by magento api: /customer/token don't sure about the name of the API)
- On magento site (on sub-domain) i created an event-listener on each page except logout page, on this observer i check if there is a token in cookie, if yes i check that this token is present in magento database, if yes i login user

It's work perfectly but you need to be on the same domain or sub-domain for cookies

Will