# How to programmatically login an admin user?

Tags: magento2, admin, magento2.3, admin-login, admin-user

I am on Magento 2.3.1 and I am trying to login an admin user automatically given their username. I have tried using the `Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session` class like this:

```
$this->_authSession->setUser($adminUserName);
$this->_authSession->processLogin();
$this->_authSession->refreshAcl();
$this->_authSession->prolong();
```

and then redirecting like this:

```
return $this->_backendUrl->getUrl('admin/dashboard/index');
```

but it keeps giving me the login prompt instead of the dashboard even though this test:

```
var_dump($this->_authSession->isLoggedIn());
```

returns the boolean True.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: want to login in admin panel programmaticlly?

Comment: yes, I am trying to automatically log into the admin panel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what i managed to do (based on [How to perform auto-login in Magento2 admin?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/122797/how-to-perform-auto-login-in-magento2-admin/122801#122801)) and is working

```
?php
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

class TestApp extends \Magento\Framework\App\Http implements \Magento\Framework\AppInterface {

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
) {

    $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
    $this->_eventManager = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Event\Manager');
    $this->_areaList = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\AreaList');
    $this->_request = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http');
    $this->_response = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http');
    $this->_configLoader = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ConfigLoaderInterface');
    $this->_state = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
    $this->_filesystem = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Filesystem');
    $this->registry = $this->_objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\Registry');

    parent::__construct($objectManager, $this->_eventManager, $this->_areaList, $this->_request, $this->_response, $this->_configLoader, $this->_state, $this->_filesystem, $this->registry);


}

public function launch()
{
    $areaCode = 'adminhtml';
    $username = 'superadmin3';

    $this->_state->setAreaCode($areaCode);

    $this->_request->setPathInfo('/admin');

    $this->_objectManager->configure($this->_configLoader->load($areaCode));

    /** @var \Magento\User\Model\User $user */
    $user = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\User\Model\User')->loadByUsername($username);

    /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $session */
    $session = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session');
    $session->setUser($user);
    $session->processLogin();

    if ($session->isLoggedIn()) {
        $cookieManager = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface');
        $cookieValue = $session->getSessionId();
        if ($cookieValue) {
            $sessionConfig = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Backend\Model\Session\AdminConfig');
            $cookiePath = str_replace('autologin.php', 'index.php', $sessionConfig->getCookiePath());
            $cookieMetadata = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory')
                ->createPublicCookieMetadata()
                ->setDuration(3600)
                ->setPath($cookiePath)
                ->setDomain($sessionConfig->getCookieDomain())
                ->setSecure($sessionConfig->getCookieSecure())
                ->setHttpOnly($sessionConfig->getCookieHttpOnly());
            $cookieManager->setPublicCookie($sessionConfig->getName(), $cookieValue, $cookieMetadata);
            /** @var \Magento\Security\Model\AdminSessionsManager $adminSessionManager */
            $adminSessionManager = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Security\Model\AdminSessionsManager');
            $adminSessionManager->processLogin();

        }

        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\UrlInterface $backendUrl */
        $backendUrl = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Backend\Model\UrlInterface');
        $path = $backendUrl->getStartupPageUrl();
        $url = $backendUrl->getUrl($path);
        $url = str_replace('autologin.php', 'index.php', $url);
        header('Location:  '.$url);
        exit;
    }
    return $this->_response;
}
}

$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('TestApp');
$bootstrap->run($app);
```

Comment: Thanks ! It works ! However, in magento 2.3.1 an instance of the class `Magento\Backend\Model\Session\AdminConfig` must be used in `setPublicCookie` to get the correct session name. Otherwise, the cookie is named PHPSESSID and the redirect will prompt the admin panel login page

Comment: if its works for you then click on the tick mark to help other people as well and also upvote as well. thanks

Comment: Yeah, just waiting for the edit to get accepted so it works for others as well. Thanks !

Comment: It doesn't make sense to edit a file in root.

Answer (score 0):

> **Try This Code**

```
<?php
/*
 * @author      Mahesh Makwana
 */
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Area;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $objectManager;

    protected $request;

    protected $configLoader;

    protected $adminUser;

    protected $authSession;

    protected $cookieManager;

    protected $adminConfig;

    protected $cookieMetadataFactory;

    protected $adminSessionsManager;

    protected $urlInterface;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ConfigLoaderInterface $configLoader,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
        \Magento\User\Model\UserFactory $adminUser,
        \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $authSession,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface $cookieManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory $cookieMetadataFactory,
        \Magento\Backend\Model\Session\AdminConfig $adminConfig,
        \Magento\Security\Model\AdminSessionsManager $adminSessionsManager,
        \Magento\Backend\Model\UrlInterface $urlInterface,
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager

    ) {
        $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->adminUser = $adminUser;
        $this->authSession = $authSession;
        $this->cookieManager = $cookieManager;
        $this->cookieMetadataFactory = $cookieMetadataFactory;
        $this->adminConfig = $adminConfig;
        $this->adminSessionsManager = $adminSessionsManager;
        $this->urlInterface = $urlInterface;
        $this->configLoader = $configLoader;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Execute.
     *
     * @return Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
        try {
            $username = 'admin'; // add your admin user name

            $this->request->setPathInfo('/admin');

            $this->objectManager->configure($this->configLoader->load(Area::AREA_ADMINHTML));

            /** @var \Magento\User\Model\User $user */
            $user = $this->adminUser->create()->loadByUsername($username);

            /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $session */
            $this->authSession->setUser($user);
            $this->authSession->processLogin();
            if ($this->authSession->isLoggedIn()) {
                $cookieValue = $this->authSession->getSessionId();
                if ($cookieValue) {
                    $cookiePath = $this->adminConfig->getCookiePath();
                    $cookieMetadata = $this->cookieMetadataFactory
                        ->createPublicCookieMetadata()
                        ->setDuration(3600)
                        ->setPath($cookiePath)
                        ->setDomain($this->adminConfig->getCookieDomain())
                        ->setSecure($this->adminConfig->getCookieSecure())
                        ->setHttpOnly($this->adminConfig->getCookieHttpOnly());
                    $this->cookieManager->setPublicCookie($this->adminConfig->getName(), $cookieValue, $cookieMetadata);

                    /** @var \Magento\Security\Model\AdminSessionsManager $adminSessionsManager */
                    $this->adminSessionsManager->processLogin();

                    $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->urlInterface->getUrl('admin/dashboard/index'));
                    return $resultRedirect;
                } else{
                    $this->messageManager->addError(__('invalid cookie value.'));
                }
            } else {
                $this->messageManager->addError(__('invalid admin user.'));
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addError(__('Something went wrong while login to admin.'));
        }

        $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
        return $resultRedirect;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Admin login programmatically using root script**

https://www.integerbyteblog.in/magento/admin-login-programmatically-in-magento-2/